# Is it correct to say "Let's go to see your grandma"?

Tags: verbs

My 7-year-old daughter's English textbook has the following conversation:

> *Son:* What day is today?
>   *Mother:* It's Saturday. Let's **go to see** your grandma.

Is *"go to see"* here correct? Should it be *"go see"*?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it as shown above, though other forms are correct as well, and may be more common in some parts of the world.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my summary. If people can offer improvements, I'll edit.

1. In the US and the UK, it is correct to to say,  "It's Saturday. Let's go to see your grandma."
2. In the US, an informal version is,  "It's Saturday. Let's go see your grandma."
3. In the UK, the most likely version you will hear is,  "It's Saturday. Let's go and see your grandma."
4. See comment below re the usage of 'go and see' in the US.

Comment: "Go and see" is not uncommon in the US either, though likely it's a regional thing.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you are right it should be "Let's go see your grandma", because you see the infinitive verbs will follow only certain verbs.

Here's a list of verbs that an infinitive verb can follow,
http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/verbs/infinitive-verb.html

Edited:

Well based on my first research I posted my above response,  now after considering the comments below and on doing further research its looks like both are right..  but its just the usage of the former has become very less over years and it has become the trend to use the latter.

Comment: It's probably better to call the use of "see" in "go see" a bare infinitive, and the use of "to see" in "go to see" a to-infinitive.  As your cite explains.  The list of verbs at that cite does not exclude "go" from taking either type of infinitive.  Modern usage prefers "go see," but that hasn't been the case for very long.  Please consider correcting your answer.  (Check here for historical usage: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=go+see%2Cgo+to+see&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgo%20see%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgo%20to%20see%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: It is unlikely that anyone in Britain would say *go see*. The so-called *bare infinitive* following *go* is an Americanism. In Britain you either *go to see* or *go and see*.

Comment: The bare infinitive (without *to*) is *go*, but as WS2 points out, in the UK many would say: "We must/should/could/would/will go to + Verb" (OR) Let's go to visit/see nan"